# Computing the Inverse of a given $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ matrix using the result from a card shuffling Markov Chain

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value

Let $A$ be a $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ matrix with $(1-1/N)$ as the entry on the diagonal and $-1/N$ elsewhere.

Now, consider an experiment where we have $N$ cards labeled from $1$ to $N$. We start by picking a card, at random, and shuffling it each time it's not the "$N$" card. We stop this process when we pick the $N$ labeled card.

The task is to create a transition matrix for the card shuffling experiment. Then to calculate the expected value of the number of times you will have drawn cards from $\{1, 2, ..., N-1\}$ before you have drawn the "$N$" labeled card (we are assumed to have picked a random card *j* as our first card and want to know the number of times we have drawn cards before we got to the "$N$" card).

From ALL these results, I'm to find a formula/result for the Inverse of the given $A$ matrix.

I have calculated my transition matrix for the card shuffling experiment as an NxN matrix with $1/N$ in all entries except the Nth row where $N$ is an absorbing state. From this, I calculated the matrix of transient states which was an $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ matrix with $1/N$ in all of its entries. I'm confused as to how to figure out the expected value of the number of times before we reach the "$N$" card and as to how that all leads to me calculating the formula for the inverse of matrix $A$. Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix $A$ is given by $I_{n-1} - \frac1nJ_{n-1}.$
The matrix $J_n$ (matrix of all ones) has eigenvalue $n$ (with eigenvector being in the direction $\mathbf{1}.$) and the of the eigenvalues are zero. So, the matrix $A$ takes the vector $\mathbf{1}$ to the vector $\frac1n \mathbf{1}$ and any vector with sum of elements $0$ to itself. So, change the basis to an orthogonal basis whose first element is the unit vector in direction of $\mathbf{1}_{n-1}$ and the inverse is trivial to compute.